# To show that $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}$ does not exist using ${\epsilon- \delta}$ definition.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

To show that $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}$ does not exist using ${\epsilon- \delta}$ definition.

Let  $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}=l$

Set ${{\epsilon}\gt{|1-l|}}$

Consider $| {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}-l|=|\frac{|z|^2(1-l)}{|\bar{z}|^2}|<|1-l| \gt \epsilon $ for every ${\delta}$ such that $0\lt|z|<\delta$

Therefore the given limit does not exist.

please correct my explanation if I have made any mistake.

Comment: How do you obtain $|z|^2$ and $|\bar z|^2$?

Comment: Can you give me example of z for which $|z|^2$ and ${|\bar{z}|^2}$ are not equal.

Comment: I meant I lacked  a fuller justification.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote doesn't work since $$\left | {\left(\frac{z} {\bar{z}}\right)^2}-l\right |\neq\left |\frac{|z|^2(1-l)}{|\bar{z}|^2}\right |.$$ Paul Frost already wrote why. You might have mistakenly used $|z|^2 = z^2$, which is true for real numbers, but not for all complex numbers. Remember that $|z|^2 = z\overline z$ holds for all complex numbers instead.

So, how would one approach the problem, using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition? First let us see what the function $z\mapsto (z/\overline z)^2$ does. If we write $z = re^{it}$ (or $z = r(\cos t + i\sin t)$ if you prefer it that way), we can easily see that $$\left(\frac z{\overline z}\right)^2 = \left(\frac {re^{it}}{re^{-it}}\right)^2 = (e^{2it})^2 = e^{4it} = \cos(4t) + i\sin(4t). \tag{1}$$

Thus, our function normalizes our $z$ and quadruples its argument.

Now, assume that the limit $L$ exists. Let us write $L = re^{it}$. Considering what our function does, we want to choose $z$ such that $(z/\overline z)^2$ is as far away as possible from $L$. Since $(z/\overline z)^2$ always ends up on the unit circle and the complex number furthest apart from $L$ on the unit circle is $-L/|L| = -e^{it}$ (if $L\neq 0$, otherwise all the numbers on the unit circle are equally far away), we want $(z/\overline z)^2 = -e^{it}.$ Using $(1)$ we can quickly see that $z = \frac{\delta}{2}e^{\frac 14 i(t+\pi)}$ works for any $\delta > 0$. This scaling factor also makes sure that $|z| = \frac \delta 2$.

Finally, we are ready to prove that the limit $L = re^{it}$, in fact, cannot exist. Take $\varepsilon = 1$ and any $\delta > 0$. Now choose $z = \frac{\delta}{2}e^{\frac 14 i(t+\pi)}$ as above. Then we have $0<|z|<\delta$, but
$$|(z/\overline z)^2 - L| = |-e^{it}-re^{it}| = |e^{it}||1+r| = 1+r\geq \varepsilon,$$
which is contradiction with the assumption that $L$ is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your proof.

1. Equation
   $$| {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}-l|=|\frac{|z|^2(1-l)}{|\bar{z}|^2}| \tag{1}$$
   is not plausible (and in fact, it is not true, see below). You have
   $$ | {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}-l|=\frac{|z^2-l\bar{z}^2|}{|\bar{z}|^2} .$$
2. If $(1)$ were true, then you would get $| {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}-l|= |1-l|$ (and not $<$). Under your assumption ${{\epsilon}\gt{|1-l|}}$ you get $| {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}-l| < \epsilon$. You could try to assume ${{\epsilon} <{|1-l|}}$ instead, but this does not work. In fact, if $l$ exists, then necessarily $l = 1$ (take $z_n = 1/n$). This would imply $| {(\frac{z} {\bar{z}})^2}-1|= 0$ for all $z$ which is not true.

I think it is much easier to consider the two sequences $z_n = 1/n$ and $z'_n = \lambda/n$, where $\lambda^2 = i$.